# Nuxt js how to use the vue-resource to get jsonp?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource, nuxt.js

You need to get a jsonp and put them in store Vuex, how to do it if in 
how to do it if you can not use the fetch not this

```js
import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  fetch ({ store, params }) {
    var self = this
    return self.$http.jsonp('https://api.vk.com/method/market.get?..')
      .then((res) => {
        store.commit('FETCH_DATAS', res.response)
      })
  },
```

Comment: I see that this is the old question and there are no details, so I can not provide the full/correct answer. Basically jsonp uses "document" which is available just in browsers, so can be used just in client side rendering. If anyone else will have similar issue and needs help - open a new question and ping me.